# Setting TCP window size on older kernel

Tags: centos, tcp, sysctl

I have this:

`Linux 3.10.0 #1 SMP Thu Apr 22 16:18:59 MSK 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Trying to set this in sysctl.conf

```
net.core.wmem_max = 12874368
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 42380 12874368
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 31536 12874368
```

Result:

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem: No such file or directory
```

The files indeed do not exist in `/proc/sys/net/***`. Since `net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen=3` is supported these options also should be avaibale.

How else can I tweak them? It's OpenVZ if that matters.